# Objective-C: what is private what is not?

Tags: objective-c, private

Why are people using

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController 
{
@private
    UIButton* button_;
}
```

@private declarations in public headers? Declaring a variable inside an implementation yields the same result, doesn't it? It feels strange to me, I thought a public header should only contain really public members. What to do with protected members?

```
@implementation ViewController
    UIButton* button_;
@end
```

The only difference I know of is that this variable is only visible inside the current compilation unit (the .m file, right?)

Does the same hold true for methods? I could compile fine with proper method ordering or forward declarations. Why do people care to declare categories for private methods? For testing purposes only?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The variable declaration inside the `@implementation` block will create a global variable, and not an instance variable. Instance variables need to be defined as part of the `@interface`.

While you can create an additional `@interface` block, by means of a category or extension, but it can only contain method declarations, and not instance variables.

Comment: I think they are not, it's just a global variable in the `C` way of declaring things. Remember that `Objective-C` is a strict superset of `C`, so all `C` rules still apply.

Comment: i have confirmed it is a global variable, you we're right. I'm surprised the compiler does not issue a warning when declaring a non-static variable _inside_ @implementation

Comment: warning you of what? Declaring a standard global variable?

Comment: You can't declare them in an separate interface block. Only the original class @interface block can declare instance variables. I think you can create a class extension or category to declare additional methods only.

Answer (score 4):

I would say that while it might "feel" wrong to you to put private instance variables in a supposedly public header, I wouldn't worry about it.

Take a look at pretty much any header file for a Cocoa class (except for the cluster classes), and you'll see that Apple declares their instance variables in their public header files.

Since Apple is OK with it, I don't think you have much to worry about.  =)

FYI: All instance variables are protected by default.

Answer (score 3):

> Does the same hold true for methods?

No, methods are visible to any part of the program. If you know the selector you can callit.

> I could compile fine with proper method ordering or forward declarations. Why do people care to declare categories for private methods? For testing purposes only?

Private categories are a form of forward declaration. You can think of them as if they were C prototypes.

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

@private is referring only to the iVars.

By default you can access ivars of an instance like so:- `id iShouldNotDoThis = foo->bar;`

@private means you can't access the ivar like that and have to use the access methods.

```
id thisIsBetter = [foo bar];
```

Nothing to do with private categories or methods.

Comment: wouldn't i get a compiler/linker error when trying to access button_ if it was only declared inside the implementation file?

Comment: it's not in the implementation file.. it's in the public header, declared @private

Comment: sorry, i meant MY example aboce where button_ is declared int the implementation file

Comment: ahh, i see. The first option you have is like i describe above. The second option is completely different, as pgb says - a C global variable (That doesn't mean that it is static)